# Using Python Regex to Separate a Coordinate Pair into X and Y Commponents

Tags: python, regex, latex

Suppose I have the following segment of LaTex Code:

```
  & $(-1,1)$
  & $(0,\infty)$
```

How would I use regex in python in order to separate out the coordinate pair into its x and y components?

For example, for the above segment I would want to receive:

```
x: -1 y: 1
x: 0 y: \infty
```

Currently I am using:

```
c = map(str,re.findall(r'-?\S',range))
a = c[1]
b = c[3]
```

However this only matches integers and not the "\infty" 's I need.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` :

```
>>> import re
>>> s="""  & $(-1,1)$
...   & $(0,\infty)$"""
>>> re.findall(r'\((.*),(.*)\)',s)
[('-1', '1'), ('0', '\\infty')]
```

and for convert the coordinates to `int` you can use the following list comprehension :

```
>>> l=[[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in coor] for coor in re.findall(r'\((.*),(.*)\)',s)]
[['-1', 1], [0, '\\infty']]

>>> l[0]
['-1', 1]
>>> l[0][0]
'-1'
```

Comment: @KasraAD Could I print this as x.group(0) and x.group(1) ?

Comment: @zara no `re.findall` doesn't support that! for get coordinates separately you can just use indexing

Comment: I am unsure as to how to do that since I am a novice. @kasra

Comment: @zara i edit the answer! and if you just want to use grouping you need `re.search`. but you can match one coordinate with it!

Comment: thanks do you mind showing me how to do this with re.search? @kasra